# Trying To Understand Which Play Library To Use

Tags: scala, playframework, play-ws

What is the difference between the following libraries:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ahc-ws-standalone" % "LATEST_VERSION"
```

and

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ahc-ws" % "LATEST_VERSION"
```

I am just trying to figure which is the correct one to use. What I did was to create a Play module in a separate library and I want to inject that into a Play application. But when I used the first library listed above, it only offers a `StandaloneWSClient`. When I injected that into a Play application it couldn't bind an implementation to it. But when I switched the second library, it offers a `WSClient` which the Play application could find an implementation to bind to as it already has one which you can specify in the build.sbt definition ie `ws`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Play project you should use `play-ahc-ws` which is usually added like so

```
libraryDependencies += ws
```

The [`ws`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/649758cb68ead0dcc0aac747dc11081d8ae19feb/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L75) value comes from Play's sbt plugin

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.1")
```

On the other hand, [`play-ahc-ws-standalone`](https://github.com/playframework/play-ws) is a HTTP client in its own right which can be used outside Play projects, just how one could use, for example, `scalaj-http` or `requests-scala` HTTP clients which are in no way aware of Play.

The difference is documented by [Play 2.6 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/WSMigration26).